# Separate custom ExoPlayer controls from video

Tags: android, exoplayer

How to add custom controls to ExoPlayer that don't show up on the video?

Comment: Could you explain more?? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Normally ExoPlayer shows control on top of the video. What I wish to achieve is to display the controls below the video, not on top of the video.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using a [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/working-with-a-media-session) along with TransportControls. If your player listens to the TransportControls you can trigger these controls in your code without having to show any UI.